# Optionally control meta tag permissions individually module

Tags: drupal-7

For : Drupal 7

I would like to use the Optionally control meta tag permissions individually module however it looks like it hasn't been updated in 6 years, does anyone know if it is still usable for Drupal 7?

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/1961354

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link you are referring to points to a feature request (no individual module), the feature have been merged a while ago. This should be enough to convince you (latest commit 1 month ago)

[image]

Here is the list of metatag submodules :

```
 metatag_app_links
 metatag_context
 metatag_dc
 metatag_dc_advanced
 metatag_devel
 metatag_facebook
 metatag_favicons
 metatag_google_cse
 metatag_google_plus
 metatag_hreflang
 metatag_importer
 metatag_mobile
 metatag_opengraph
 metatag_opengraph_products
 metatag_panels
 metatag_twitter_cards
 metatag_verification
 metatag_views
```

Comment: As you may have guessed I don't know a lot about Drupal. Is your screenshot for the: metatag module or the Optionally control meta tag permissions individually module (this is the one I am querying)?

Comment: This is not a module but a feature that have been merged a while ago yes.

Comment: @Jandal you can upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful.